# How to mix web.xml and AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer in Spring

Tags: spring

I would like to ask if there is already a project developed by web.xml, but now I want to add some features, such as interceptors, to this project through `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`. Can it be implemented

```
public class WebConfig extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{MvcConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new UserInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }
}
```

This is my problem:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!

Comment: The first and second question you have to ask yourself, why?. If you really want yes you can **but** there are some things to consider. There can only be one root context, you have 2 because there is one in your `web.xml` as well, that simply won't work.